# Rails model new attribute doesn't show up in backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I never worked with backbone before so please have patience.

I added a new attribute to my rails model and it worked fine (checked with rails console). However the attribute doesn't show up in the backbone model. I've already added the new attribute (**category**) to the whitelist in the backbone model

```
class Models.Program extends Models.Base
  paramRoot: 'program'
  urlRoot: '/api/programs'

  defaults:
    locale: "en"

  whitelist: ["name", "internal_name", "site_id", "locale", "target_description",
    "introduction", "display_mode_class", "timezone", "start_at", "end_at",
    "diploma_text", "diploma_enabled", "category"]
```

What else should I do for the new attribute to show up in backbone? Is there a "link" between the rails controller and the backbone model?

Thanks

Comment: Models.Base is the backbone model. That is what I'm trying to understand: how/where does this new attribute is passed to Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute will be available in Backbone model only if it is either passed in constructor (`new Model({prop1: 'value'}`) or set manuall (`modelInstance.set('attributeName', 'value')`).

Probably you want to achieve it by first approach, what suggests you don't pass this property in JSON from server (or delete it somewhere in client code).

Double check with what data is this model initialized.